# Is there anyway to hide the credential values in variables panel?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I have created the credential for my email id and password but when I use them in a robot and the value of those credentials is visible in variables panel, is there any way through which I can hide my credentials even in variables panel?
In this program, I am trying to login in Gmail, it works perfectly but doesn't want any of my credentials value in variables panel.

```
selenium.open chrome url google.com
delay 2
window ✱Google✱ 
selenium.click search gb_70 by id
selenium.click search //*[@id="identifierId"] by xpath
♥login = ♥credential⟦gmail:login⟧
♥password = ♥credential⟦gmail:password⟧
keyboard ♥login 
keyboard ⋘enter⋙
delay 2
selenium.click search //*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input by xpath
keyboard ♥password
keyboard ⋘enter⋙
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a credential variable value into another variable, the value will be visible in the Variables panel. If you want to prevent that, simply don't create another variables containing credential values.

```
selenium.open chrome url google.com
delay 2
window ✱Google✱ 
selenium.click search gb_70 by id
selenium.click search //*[@id="identifierId"] by xpath 
keyboard ♥credential⟦gmail:login⟧ 
keyboard ⋘enter⋙
delay 2
selenium.click search //*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input by xpath
keyboard ♥credential⟦gmail:password⟧
keyboard ⋘enter⋙
```